# d3.js: can't get padding working on rangeRoundBands?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to draw a bar chart with padding between the bars, but I can't get `rangeRoundBands` to insert padding - though [the docs tell me this is possible](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-ordinal_rangeBands), so I'm doing something wrong.

This is my code:

```
var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
 .rangeRoundBands([margin.left, width], 0.1, 0.1);

... 

ap_bars.transition().duration(1000)
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * x0.rangeBand();
  })
  .attr("width", x0.rangeBand());
```

But the bars are all stacked together.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6pnem/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're changing the size of the band with padding correctly, but the way you're plotting the bars will also put them side by side right next to each other.  As you increase the padding, you'll see the that the bars just get skinnier and skinnier but stay pinched together.

Instead of using a constant based on the data index (`i * x0.rangeBand()`) you need to position the bar based on scaled data: (`x0(d)`).  You'll probably want to adjust the position of the bar so that center of the bar is the center of each band: (`x0(d) - x0.rangeBand() * 0.5`).